# Will Python's "in" keyword ever return True for an empty list?

Tags: python, list, keyword, empty-list

Stated simply, is there any value `x` for which the following holds in Python?

```
(x in []) == True
```

This is a rudimentary question, but a negative answer would have to exhaust all possibilities: i.e., "There is no type and no constant of any given type such that `x in []` returns the value `True`." It may be the case, however, that demonstrating or refuting this exhaustivity is very simple.

It is easy to test that various values, as expected, are *not* members of the empty list:

```
>>> None in []
False
>>> False in []
False
>>> [] in []
False
>>> "" in []
False
>>> {} in []
False
```

Is this ever *not* the case?

Comment: No, there is never a case where `in` will return True where the right hand of the operator is an empty list. I don't mean to be rude but the clue is in the name, an empty list has nothing "in" it

Comment: Seems a pretty straightforward thing that you can simply try, and you must have some scenario in mind: So why don’t you just try it?

Comment: @barny You can't use that method to prove a negative. All it will tell you is that it doesn't return True for the values you tried, there might be something you didn't think of.

Comment: Is this question purely for educational reasons?

Comment: Happily for you, Python is open source, so you can research your question yourself by looking at the implementation of `in` and observing what it does if the target list is empty. Tried that?

Comment: @Barmar I agree if you haven't yet thought of it then you can't write a program to try it, but in that situation you don't need to write a program to try it because you haven't yet thought of it. It's all very well asking blue-sky questions but you tend to get blue sky answers.

Comment: @barny If you're trying to write bullet-proof code, or you're trying to write test cases, you need to know what the corner cases are so you can protect against them or test that the code works with them. It seems perfectly reasonable to look for assistance if you're not sure what they are.

Comment: Maybe you should use a strongly typed language then you don't need to do so much work to be sure inputs are known types? I'm surprised that you asking the question here implies you might trust the answer of some anon SO user. I still don't understand why you don't check that source code. For example the build-time tests for lists are entirely visible - at least you could assure your self of how comprehensive they are.

Comment: To address some issues: (1) As far as "the clue is in the name," Python is not English, and new developers run into problems when they take the "natural language"-ness of certain Python statements too far; (2) While broad, this question could arise anytime a script using potentially empty lists allows those lists to contain a variety of variable types; (3) The question is not seeking a data structure that fools the `in` keyword -- it seeks a simple proof/explanation of whether or not it can ever be the case that `x in []` is `True`. (And if the answer is in the docs, it is not explicit there.)

Answer (score -1):

You could create a subclass of `list` for which this would be the case although I don't know why you would ever do this

```
class Foo(list):
    def __in__(self, bar):
        return True

bar = Foo()
None in l
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last line be `None in bar`?

Comment: The point was not to find a data structure that "gets around" the `in` keyword. See my comment under the original post.